# Convert table to string, then back again

Tags: serialization, lua, lua-table

I would like to know how to convert a table to a string, and then back again.

I want to use the sockets module to send a table, but I must do it through a string.

I would like to do it like this:

```
a = { 1, 2, 3 } -- create table
b = tostring(a) -- convert table to string
c = totable(b) -- convert string back to table
```

Comment: In general, you can't. (Some functions, etc can't be serialized.) Are you concerned only with a sequence of numbers, as in your example? If so, you could do that.

Comment: I mainly didn't want to use string format, as many tuts have shown me. It's just not all that convenient for what I want to do.

Comment: @RyanVincent What I specifically want to do is send coordinates and other information from a client to a server. This is for a game using the love2d engine. It would be a lot simpler to just send a table rather than sending formatted strings, as all I have to do to access it is `player.x = ...` instead of gluing everything together, and pulling it apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you can't serialize everything easily, but you **can** serialize a great many things.  For this kind of IPC, JSON is the current *lingua franca*, and I highly recommend it, especially since you can fairly safely interchange with many other languages out there.

Lua has [several implementations](http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules), but check out [this one especially](http://json.luaforge.net), as it works well, is pretty stable, and there's a good level of maintenance activity on github.  Example code:

```
json = require("json")
encoded = json.encode(someVar)
decoded = json.decode(someStr)
```

Comment: This will work, however, LOVE engine does not support JSON. But, since this does answer my question, I will select it as answer.

Comment: This implementation of JSON is native lua, so you might be able to copypasta the whole thing in your code if you control both sides.  Good luck in any case :-)

Comment: Alright. I can only hope though. I do in fact know this will work serverside, so that's 50% done.

Comment: With pluto you can serialize entire Lua state :)

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of existing Lua libraries for this. 
See http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization
Table serialization functions are pretty straight forward, writing your own is a good learning exercise.

PS. Just checked...The love2D API has a table serialization library in it already.